# C++ primer plus Chapter14 No-type Stack

Tags: c++, templates

why does
`ArrayTP<double,12> eggweights; ArrayTP<double,13> donuts;` generate two separate classes, but `Stack<int> eggs(12); Stack<int> dunkers(13)` generate just one declaration? Shouldn't they be two stacks: one is **eggs** stack, another is **dunkers** stack?

Comment: At the first example the data type is different. At the second one just the contents are different!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that is what your declarations state.

```
ArrayTP<double,12> eggweights;
ArrayTP<double,13> donuts;
```

The type of the first variable is `ArrayTP<double,12>`, while that of the second is `ArrayTP<double,13>`. These are different.

```
Stack<int> eggs(12);
Stack<int> dunkers(13);
```

The type of the first variable is `Stack<int>`, while that of the second is `Stack<int>`. These are the same.

The `12` and `13` for `eggs` and `dunkers` are parameters for their constructors. Expecting different types to come from that is like expecting different types for the following:

```
std::string foo{"hello"};
std::string bar{"world"};
```

Comment: Thanks.  My comprehension was wrong. I thought the book said that Stack<int> eggs(12) and Stack<int> dunkers(13) create just one Stack, which means the second Stack "dunkers" overwrite the "eggs". So this made me confused. But now , I understand that they are just one template class type and two different objects.       Thanks! I have changed my last horrible questions. @JaMiT